# How to extract rows in date condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
A  B 
a1 2016-10-24
b1 2016-11-25 
b2 2017-02-26
a2 2016-11-23
b2 2017-01-03
b3 2017-03-24
```

In Step 1, I extract the rows starting with a:

`df[df.A.str.startswith("a")]`

```
A  B 
a1 2016-10-24
a2 2016-11-23
```

Next, I would like to extract the rows in which the date in column B is in the next 2 months to the extracted rows in step 1.

So in the example dataframe, I would like to extract rows in which column B is from `2016-10-24` to `2016-12-24`, or from `2016-11-23` to `2017-01-23`.

As a result, I would extract rows whose column B is from `2016-10-24` to `2017-01-23`.

My desired result is below.

```
A  B 
a1 2016-10-24
b1 2016-11-25 
a2 2016-11-23
b2 2017-01-03
```

How do I extract rows with these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first select `B` by condition, then add `2` months to `end_date` date, get `start_date` date as `min` and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.A.str.startswith("a"), 'B']
print (df1)
0   2016-10-24
3   2016-11-23
Name: B, dtype: datetime64[ns]

end_date = df1.max() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)
start_date = df1.min()
print (start_date)
2016-10-24 00:00:00
print (end_date)
2017-01-23 00:00:00

print (df[(df.B >= start_date)&(df.B <= end_date)])
    A          B
0  a1 2016-10-24
1  b1 2016-11-25
3  a2 2016-11-23
4  b2 2017-01-03
```